# How to convert string input(numbers with spaces) to dataframe in Shiny (R)?

Tags: r, shiny

In ui.R

```
textInput("numbers","New try")
# Example input, 2345 654774 647
```

In server.R

```
x = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(input$numbers, '')))
```

Output is

```
2 3 4 5 NA 6 5 4 7 7 4 NA 6 4 7
```

This is converting the numbers to atomic vectors. I want the numbers to be converted to dataframe with the numbers preserved. For example, 2345 654774 647
in dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex to search for whole numbers in the string instead of separating into individual numbers. From this all the matches can be put into a data frame.

```
library(stringr)

input<-"2345 654774 647"

Match<-str_match_all(input, "\\d+")

DF<-as.data.frame(Match)

names(DF)<-("Test")
DF
    Test
1   2345
2 654774
3    647
```

Comment: It says could not find the function str_match_all

Comment: Try `stringr::str_match_all`

Comment: Sorry, make sure to install and use the package, `stringr`

Comment: Used stringr::str_match_all. Now there is error - Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'